# Trying to use Cognito to download files from S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS S3 as a backend for sound file storage in an iOS app. I can upload sound files to the bucket as I wish, but I am having trouble to make the download work.

I was first hoping to make things work using `PFFile`, but since I did not succeed as expected, I did some research and had the impression that using `Cognito` was the way to go. Since it is my firstime to use it, I may well be missing some important part.

Here is the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    ..........

    // For the AWSS3 configuration:
    let poolID = "us-east-1:123.........",
    credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1,
                                                       identityPoolId: poolID)
    let awsConfig = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .APNortheast1,
                                            credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = awsConfig

    return true
}
```

At some point I have this code executed:

```
transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
```

For downloading the sound file, this code is run:

```
let soundFileName = ....,
downloadFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(soundFileName),
downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
downloadRequest?.bucket = "theappbucket"
downloadRequest?.key = soundFileName
downloadRequest?.downloadingFileURL = downloadFileURL

transferManager.download(downloadRequest!).continueWith(
    executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(),
    block: {
        (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error in \(#function)\n" + error.localizedDescription)
            print("Error in \(#function)\n\(error)")
            return nil
        }
        .....
    });
```

Here I get this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 11.)
UserInfo={HostId=ND....../FY=, Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=EAC.....}
```

Having some doubts, I have also tried using `.USEast1` instead of `.APNortheast1`, in which case the error becomes:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 0.)
```

But since my bucket is set in `Asia Pacific (Tokyo)` I presume the correct setting is `.APNortheast1`.

**Can someone point out some problem in what I am doing?**

Comment: try this config 

`let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, endpoint: AWSEndpoint(region: .USEast1, service: .S3, url: URL(string:"https://s3.myServar.com")),credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are missing permissions in the Cognito Role. Looks like you are using unauth access in Cognito. Please attach S3 GetObject permissions to your Cognito Role in the IAM console

Comment: I did not change the permissions, but started to use a different approach following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-integrate-an-existing-bucket.html. It is now working. I don't exactly know why it was not working before. Maybe I did something wrong on the way or the tutorial I followed was missing some information.